# Postgres materialized view of last n months

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

I want to keep data of last 12 months in a materialized view in Postgresql.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS last_12_months AS 
SELECT a, b, c FROM mytable 
WHERE created_at > date_trunc('day',('now'::timestamp - '1 year'::interval)));
```

The problem is that 'now' is evaluated in view creation so data will grow forever and I would like to have a fixed range of data.

I saw that views doesn't accept parameters. I thought drop/create view everyday but I'm sure that there are better alternatives.

Comment: [Refresh view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html) on daily basis?

Comment: This  doesn't work because refresh does not evaluate now. If i describe the view now was replaced in the view creation and have fixed value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you need I found the problem. The difference between the original and the solution is 'now' vs now()

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW IF NOT EXISTS last_12_months AS 
SELECT a, b, c FROM mytable 
WHERE created_at > date_trunc('day',(now() - interval '1 year')));
```